# Monitoring current tab location.href in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I want to monitor user activity in Firefox browser, I need to know it's location.href in current tab. For this I use **content.location.href** , but I need the code when this location.href changes. I need to know what events should I listen and on what objects in the browser.

Some of my code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){
    window.removeEventListener("load", load, false);
    myExtension.init();
},false);

var myExtension = {
  init: function() {
    var appcontent = document.getElementById("appcontent");
    appcontent.addEventListener("blur", myExtension.onPageBlur, true);
    appcontent.addEventListener("load", myExtension.onPageLoad, true);
    appcontent.addEventListener("focus", myExtension.onPageFocus, true);
  },

  onPageBlur: function () {
    // Doing something when there is no focus
  },

  onPageFocus: function(aEvent) {
    // Doing something when we get focus
  },

  onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {
    // Doing something on page load
  }
};
```

This code works, but with a little bit unwanted behavior, when you click on location bar of the browser, the blur event is fired, and difficult to work with location.href if the location.href is changed (focus and load event fired), need some rework to optimize when saving data of the user activity

I need that the code has this behavior:

- Works on tab select
- Works on tab location.href change
- Works with multiple windows of the browser

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be [using a progress listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners) for that. Your `onLocationChange` will be called every time the location of the current tab changes, you would only need to look at `aURI.spec`. The same approach is used to update the location bar in Firefox.